# Jenkins error svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am trying to configure the svn with jenkins but I get the below error. Is there any permission to be provided?

```
Unable to access file:///C:/TestProject/ : svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/TestProject/'
```

Below is the stack trace shown in the Jenkins:

```
Caused by: svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.wrap(SVNErrorMessage.java:407)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/TestProject/'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:171)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:126)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.openRepository(FSRepository.java:760)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/TestProject/'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.openRepositoryRoot(FSRepository.java:782)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.openRepository(FSRepository.java:758)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/TestProject/'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:171)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:126)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.openRepositoryRoot(FSRepository.java:781)
```

Comment: Seems to me that you need to make sure that "file:///C:/TestProject" translates to a SVN URL style type location.. type 'svn info' and use the URL from the output

Answer (score 3):

Having done some investigation on this specific error message (although it is difficult to say if this is an answer to the user's specific issue), I have determined that one cause is the default SVN plugin within a vanilla Jenkins install, especially if one is using the latest TortoiseSVN, which ships with SVN 1.8.

If one does an upgrade to [the latest version of the SVN plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin), v2.5 at the time of writing, one can see that [support for SVN 1.8 has been included](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/commit/fc8093b49321830a1a55e19910964998998bea8a). Also, don't forget to [set the SVN version number within Jenkins](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/using-jenkins-subversion-plugin). Note that it is best to also delete the project directory from the Jenkins workspace after upgrading, as there might be out-dated data stored within the workspace's `.svn` directory.

This has resolved my issue at least.

Answer (score 1):

Give jenkins ownership of the repository directory. This may be overkill, but for demonstration purposes its ok.

Im a linux user so not too hot on windows admin, but [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/27332/how-to-take-ownership-of-files-from-the-command-line) may help regarding changing ownership.